# How to populate a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to populate a simple table with 1 column using jquery.
I'm trying the code on sidebar gadget so can't figure out what the problem.

Here this is the json array I want to populate in the table.

```
[{"roomName":"admin"},{"roomName":"administrator"},{"roomName":"super Administrator"},{"roomName":"baba ji ka boota"}]
```

Here what i have done so far.

```
    $.each(dataFromMainFile, function(item) {
        $('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(item.roomName)).appendTo('#data-Table tbody');
    });
```

Below is HTML where I want this to populate

```
<table id="data-Tables" class="data-Tables" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Room</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="testingbaba2">Director Room No: 36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="testingbaba">Director Room No: 36</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what is it I am doing wrong. I cant see errors in the gadget, that's why can't figure out the problem.

Comment: You're appending to `#data-Table` (singular), but your table has the id `data-Tables` (plural).

Comment: look at source code what you  get after js code worked. This will give you a clue. Does it get changed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just passing the index, and not the element (item).

Your target id is also wrong. In your markup the ID you want is '#data-Tables', but you're passing to '#data-Table'.

Try this:

```
$.each(dataFromMainFile, function(index, item) {
    $('#data-Tables tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.roomName + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Here's a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/4yy2za6w/1/

Comment: thankyou, but it is still not appending the rows to table. :(

Comment: Thankyou, i dont think its the problem in the syntax you gave.
i am not sure why it is giving this problem, when i tried in browser i got this error.
`TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

Comment: I would have to see more code then, because the jquery I posted works fine, and answers any issues you might've had with the code you originally posted.

Comment: ok, found out why it was giving that firebug error in firefox.
It was reading my json data as a string. i dont know why it was doing that so i updated it to this
`$.each(eval(dataFromMainFile), function(index, item)` and it started working on firefox, but still issue remains the same in windows sidebar gadget.

Comment: you could try to do $.parseJSON(dataFromMainFile.trim())

Comment: parseJson didnt worked either.. so finally i moved the $.post to the flyout, i was sending the result to flyout before, cuz of which the result was turning in to string.
so now directly doing the ajax call from the file and populating table there.
But your syntax helped alot. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
    $.each(dataFromMainFile, function(item) {
        $("#myTable").append('<tr><td>' + item.roomName + '</td></tr>');
    });
```

Comment: i just checked firebug, i am getting this error.
`TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`